# Downloading photos from smartphone

Tags: usb, android, smartphone

I have a small AKAI smartphone with Android 4.2.2.

I want to download some of the photos from the smartphone to my Ubuntu computer.

I connect the smartphone with a USB cable to the computer, but, nothing happens. I don't see the smartphone in my computer and cannot download the photos.

What can I do?

EDIT: Here is the output of LSUSB when the phone, and my USB mouse, are both connected:

```
erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2188:0ae1  
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0bb4:0c03 High Tech Computer Corp.
```

When I disconnect the mouse, the line "Device 003" disappears.

When I disconnect the smartphone, the line "Device 009" disappears.

Comment: Please connect your phone, run `lsusb` and post output to your question. PLEASE DO NOT POST IT TO COMMENTS.

Comment: Most new Android devices do not have this option. @Sridhar

Comment: But it looks like it is an HTC device, not AKAI.

Comment: @Pilot6 I see the letters "AKAI" printed at the back of the device... I don't know much more than this

Comment: These codes may be wrong. This does not matter. Or it maybe like it is made by HTC, but branded as AKAI, etc.

Comment: Is this an *Ubuntu 12.04 install?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to install some `mtp` packages.

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Then you need to add your device. Run

```
sudo -H gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
```

and add there a line

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c03", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Save the file and run

```
sudo service udev restart
```

After that when you connect the phone you should see it in the launcher.

Some devices are detected as a CD with some USB drivers. In this case just eject the disk.

Comment: I did this. The final message was "udev stop/waiting...  udev start/running, process 10339". Then I plugged the device out and in again, and... nothing happened. lsusb still shows the same output (only the device number changes - it is now "Device 016". The number grows by 1 whenever I disconnect and connect the USB).

Comment: Maybe you should enable MTP in the phone. Or reboot Ubuntu.

Comment: I clicked some buttons on the smartphone, and finally something  happened: I saw a new wired connection. Now, I see two wired connections: Wired connection 1 "Ethernet (eth0)" - my default internet connection, and Wired connection 2 "Etnernet (usb0)". Is there a way to access the photos on my smartphone through this new connection?

Comment: You switched your phone to modem mode. You need to switch it to MTP mode. At the same place.

Comment: I don't find this option in my smartphone. But this is probably a question for another forum... Thanks.